# Run angular9 application on apache hosting server

Tags: angular, apache, .htaccess, deployment, hosting

I try to deploy my angular app. I run this commands `ng build` and `ng build --prod`.

And uploading to my hosting server, when I am accessing the my url it's generate dist folder and file but when I open `index.html` file in my browser it's a blank page. I fix this problem by adding `.htaccess` to my folder and everythings is right .

```
http://www.exmaple.com/ -- it's working properly
http://www.exmaple.com/home -- also
```

But when I refresh a composing path, it shows me a blank page like
http://www.exmaple.com/auth/signiIn or somethings like this

How can i solve that ?

Comment: It would be more helpful if you can provide the relevant section from .htaccess file.

Comment: my .htaccess :


RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ ./index.html